# What to do if uv editing don't work and how to delete unnecessary material in blender 4.0

Tags: materials, uv-image-editor

In the video all the problems are visible. I want to add a logo for the perfume, but for some reason it is not displayed in uv editing, but I added it to the materials. (I just wanted to remove the main material from the logo, and not remove it completely, I also don’t know how to do this). further in the video I showed that the vertexes of the logo on the cube are displayed in uv editing, but for some reason the result is not visible in the render. please help me.
The video on Google Drive is not long, about 1.30 min, please help: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14dmDOC4zgSGZTil0TRYL5WemWTmZ4zs9/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: You're doing a lot of things in the video, it's very hard to understand what you are trying to do, if you want to assign a material to an object you need to select its faces, select the material in the list of the materials and click on Assign, also make sure that you are in Material or Rendered preview mode, and that you don't have overlapping faces

Comment: My problem is that I'm trying to make a logo on a material and place it on a selected object, but for some reason the object turns completely black, and in uv editing my edges are not shown, although they are selected.
Perhaps this is due to the small size of the object, since I can easily apply a logo on a cube, but not on my small object (perfume).

Comment: Please pack your images (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I just had to select the edges and right-click and apply UV UNWRAP FACES > CUBE PROJECTION.